# Two column inheritance in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, inheritance, linq-to-sql

For example, I have a table `XSystem`:

```
SystemId|CurrencyId
--------|----------
0       |980
0       |643
1       |980
1       |643
```

Is it possible in Linq-to-SQL to create inheritance based on both columns? So there will be 4 different child classes: `XSystem_0_980`, `XSystem_0_643` and so on with different implementation?

Comment: Wait. You want types based on values in your database, not the tables?

Comment: Yes, value-based inheritance is the only one in L2SQL. But I want to have two discriminator columns. Is it possible?